# How to add two "flags" in python string literals

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-literals

How can I add 2 or more flags to string literals in Python 3.6+?

So far, I can do:

> format flag

```
my_var = 111
other_var = f'myString{my_var}' #  myString111
```

> raw flag

```
other_var = r'whatever\something'
```

This will ignore the backslash as a special character and treat it like a normal character.

But how can I join 2 flags together?

```
my_var = 111
other_var = rf'whatever\{my_var}'
```

(I want to threat backslash as a normal character at the same time I want to parse the variable to string)

Comment: `other_var = rf'whatever\{my_var}'` works fine for me in Python 3.7.3.  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: My bad, I was fooled by PyCharm (it highlight's it as an error) and by Python's console. When I wrote `other_var` on the console, it showed me `whatever\\111` (double backslashes), but if I do `print(other_var)`, it prints it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By putting them in the correct (alphabetical) order.

```py
my_var = 111
other_var = fr'whatever\{my_var}'
print(other_var)
```

outputs

```
whatever\111
```

Comment: The order of the prefixes does not matter. `fr'\{foo}'` and `rf'\{foo}'` are the same.

Comment: My bad, I was fooled by PyCharm (it highlight's it as an error) and by Python's console. When I wrote `other_var` on the console, it showed me `whatever\\111` (double backslashes), but if I do `print(other_var)`, it prints it correctly.

Comment: @Blckknght Ah, I guess I, too, was fooled by PyCharm there. :)